# What is Oracle's default password for Admin accounts (SYS and SYSTEM)?

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I have installed Oracle Express in my local system. What password do I need to provide to login as `SYSDBA`?

If I had manually installed then I would have to specify the password for SYS and SYSTEM accounts, which is obvious. I do not have admin rights to my system.

Comment: **You** provided those passwords during installation.

Comment: Do you mean [MS Software Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/core/understand/software-center)? If so it's executing a silent install with all the prompts scripted. So somebody in your organisation must know what's in the script. You need to find that person, because they can tell you the default passwords supplied.

Comment: Yes, MS Software Center!
Well , seems that is the only option now!

Answer (score 4):

Which database version is it?

Once upon a time, default passwords were

- system / manager
- sys / change_on_install

See if those help.

---

Since 11g there aren't any default passwords so - do as follows: at the operating system command prompt (Windows in my example), logged in as user that *owns* Oracle software (possibly "Administrator") connect as

```
C:\>sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Once you're logged in, change those (or any other) passwords as

```
SQL> alter user sys identified by some_password;
```

Comment: DB: Oracle XE 11g.  

I tried with the above options,It did not work for me.
Error: Invalid username/password  (ORA-01017)

Comment: I thought so. I have also added some more info; have a look, please.

Comment: Well, I tried with the command also, but I am getting ORA-01031: insufficient privileges .
After displaying error its prompting for username.

Do we need to run the  operating system command prompt  as Administrator?

Comment: Actually, as user who owns Oracle software. That *might* be Administrator. Try it.

Comment: That's again a pain to get Admin rights! is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Additional info, If you mean `Oracle XE edition`, so
The default password for the `HR`, `SYS` and `SYSTEM` accounts is `oracle`

Comment: Great answer (where is this documented????) - but for me this still returns `ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist`. :(

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Oracle Express 21c. During install there is a prompt to provide a password. Using SqlDeveloper, I was able to login with UserId - system, Password - .